# How to mix Additive/Multiplicative feature with the regular features

Tags: python-2.7

I am able to build the model for all the additive or multiplicative variables as follows,

```
 import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
 result_ad = sm.ols('Y_variable~x1+x2*x3).fit()
 result_ad.summary()
```

These x1,x2 and x3 are subset of the overall set of features, my dataset has x1,x2,x3,x4,x5.... I would like to build a common model using all these features (features which are additive/multiplicate and non-additives.multiplicatives).

But ols will not allow us to mix these variables. May be I am missing the systax or how to call ols using both the set of variables/features.